# Can I set font fallbacks in PuTTy?

Tags: fonts, putty, unicode

I want to be able to display the unicode characters `ℓ`, `∘`, `₁`, and `⊔` (among others) in emacs in screen in PuTTy.  I can see the first one by setting the font to Courier New, or I can see the second and third by setting the font to DejaVu Sans Mono.  The square cup shows up as a box in both fonts, and neither can display all of `ℓ` and `∘` and `₁`.

Is there a way to specify a font fallback in PuTTy?  (I've gotten used to Courier New, and would like to keep it, but display more characters.)  Alternatively, how do I get PuTTy to display the unicode characters I want?

Answer (score 1):

I use the [GNU Unifont](http://unifoundry.com/unifont.html) with putty for some time now. Get the font, [enable the *monospaced* flag](https://www.mail-archive.com/vim@vim.org/msg11828.html), install it and configure putty to use it.

Comment: <3 thank you! For info/other, use the script to modify the monospace flag inside the font **before** install. Also you can skip script part by checking `Allow selection of variable-pich fonts` (in Putty > Window > Appearance) AND setting font quality to `Non-Antialiased` (otherwise it laggy)(putty Release 0.70). I prefer the script method tho.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Windows font linking to accomplish this:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/globalization/mt662331

You need to edit a registry key and then reboot to see the effects:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\FontLink\SystemLink
```

[image]